# Using Flex valueObjects With Nested Arrays in XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, service

I've used Flash Builder's "connect to data/service" tool to connect to a URL of XML, which looks something like:

```
<house>
 <name>Home</home>
 <address_line1>My street</address_line1>
 <zip>12345</zip>
 <photos>
   <photo>/url/to/photo</photo>
   <photo>/url/to/another/photo</photo>
 </photos>
</house>
```

This has created a service and a package called valueObjects. In this valueObjects package is a class called "House", as I'd expect and I've worked out how to access these and their properties.

What I can't work out is how to work with the class called "Photos". Each house has a property "photos" of type Photos, which I'd expect to be an array but I can't for the life of me work out how to iterate it or see what it stores.

Can anybody help please? Hope I'm not just being dumb, but I've spent ages trying to figure it out for myself already...

Comment: Perhaps you want to post the generated code.

Comment: I was hoping it would be something obvious (turned out it was) and didn't want to mess things up with oodles of code. I sorted it in the end and now waiting for the 8 hours before I can answer my own question. In short - the XML in the URL happened to have only have one photo in the first House listed, so Flex assumed it was NOT an array. Doh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. I seem to make a habit of answering my own questions.

Here's why it didn't work -- in my XML the **first** House element happened to only have *one*  photo associated with it. Flash Builder must have decided it wasn't in fact an array just be looking at the first element in the XML.

I added another photo to the House, deleted the service and valueObject folders and recreated them based on the updated XML source.

My code now works as expected:

house.photos.photo.getItemAt(0)

You live and learn. Seems o

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `Photos` itself should contain `ArrayCollection` with instances of `Photo` inside. It will be better if you place the listing of `Photos` here to guide you more precisely.